# What is a cross OS method of converting different sized integers to and from byte arrays in C?

Tags: c, casting, endianness

I'm making a data parser/encoder that has to work on different machines of both endianness.

Metadata in the byte array dynamically declares the number of bytes used to represent each integer, and some integers (I'll know which ones) must be read in big endian, and some must be read in little endian.

I currently have the integer -> byte functions written (developing on a macOS little endian) and working on the Mac.

```
void longlong_to_bytes_big(long long num, unsigned char *byte_arr, unsigned char num_bytes)
{
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0; i<num_bytes; i++)
    byte_arr[i] = (num >> ((num_bytes - i - 1) * 8)) & 0xFF;
}

void longlong_to_bytes_little(long long num, unsigned char *byte_arr, unsigned char num_bytes)
{
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0; i<num_bytes; i++)
    byte_arr[i] = (num >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
}
```

But I'm worried this code actually only works for char, short and int on a little endian machine, and would give me the opposite endianness on a big endian machine.

Then for the other direction, I don't think I can combine all the different integer sizes into one function but I think each one should look something like this:

```
long long bytes_to_longlong_big(unsigned char *byte_arr)
{
  unsigned char i, a[8];
  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    a[i] = byte_arr[8-i-1];
  return *(long long *)a;
}

long long bytes_to_longlong_small(unsigned char *byte_arr)
{
  return *(long long *)byte_arr;
}
```

but again I'm pretty sure these will be backwards on a different endian machine due to the compilers implementation of (long long *).

Is there a machine endian agnostic way to accomplish this? Given the choice I'd prefer performance over simplicity.

The goal is that these byte arrays be in the same order, regardless of the compiler's endianness, but also regardless of endianness, the code needs to correctly interpret the byte array.

Comment: Thus far, the most portable way to transfer data is as text. This is the reson XML and JSON have become so popular to exchange data.

Answer (score 3):

You can save/exchange data in "network order" and then use functions like `ntohl` and `htonl` (and friends) when reading and writing data. These function will automatically take care of endianess of the "current" system. Consequently, you don't need to write your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You could be interested in textual formats such as [JSON](https://json.org/), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [YAML](https://yaml.org/). For human developers, they make debugging easier. You'll find many libraries supporting them.

You could also look into portable binary formats like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1)

You could find some C or C++ code generators (so a [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach) related to them (`rpcgen`, [SWIG](https://swig.org/)), and you could consider writing your own C/C++ generator with tools such as [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) or your [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) script.

For true network exchanges (e.g. [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)) - or disk IO, the bottleneck is usually the network (or the disk), not the encoding/decoding processing. That is why it usually makes sense to use textual formats.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not designing this format. It already exists, I have to write a parser/encoder for it.

Comment: Also for clarity, in my case it's not a network exchange, it's a binary file format that sits on disk (and yes is transferred between machines but not during the read/write process), so this code is not network bound.

Comment: @CSStudent7782 - You address the things in this answer that do not apply to your solution, but did not acknowledge those that do.    Clearly portable binary formats, and textual formats would apply here.

Comment: @ryyker I summarize the goal in the last paragraph of the question. Textual formats do not apply to byte arrays. And new binary formats do not apply to the old binary format I must follow (which I mention in the question).

Comment: @CSStudent7782 - Based on the literal interpretation of the last paragraph, textual formats are not explicitly excluded.  And they most certainly _can_ be used to represent the contents of a binary file.    Whether one of the industry idiomatic formats, or just a simple list of alphanumeric representations of numeric values, separated by commas in a text file, any and all textual based files are readable and parseable on any machine.